# Create Native SDKs with React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, frameworks

I want to create client libraries for my backend for iOS and Android. They will be using native services like location services.

Instead of creating a separate SDK for each, I was wondering if I would use React Native to create the SDK, and then compile(eject) it to a native iOS pod or Android aar library. Is this possible to achieve with React Native? If yes, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understood correctly, you want to develop react native libs then use in none react native projects. For example adding them to gradle or pods, But it's not available.

Because react native platform is different and needs bunch of other dependencies to be run. It's looks like running another engine inside the other one.

You can build SDK's based on Hybrid/Native frameworks and use them in those frameworks but you can't export them and use like native libraries(pod/gradle).

Except C++ programming for cross platform purposes, you should search in github or other repositories to find specific types of libraries that you need.

Comment: why? you can't export them and use like native libraries(pod/gradle)..... i was able to export everything what i need into modules like 'react-native ' `hermes` and `android-jsc`... and app working or module working fine ... there is only one problem with `@react-native-community` there are autolink modules for which use to be in react native aar but now they are exported into @community and it is crashing only on this part

Comment: @LukášŠálek : can u help me with the similar solution or where to start from, looking for similar solution

Comment: @swati you should start here: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps => you have to integrate this activity into the android module and ios framework. This will work fine you will have no problems. The problem will be later on when you will try to release it. IOS is super simple all dependencies are in POD and they are part of build from start. But for android you need to extract `hermes`, `android-jsc` and all native modules from `node_modules` (we have it automated) and you have to release this modules to maven or somewhere where you can have them as dependencies

Comment: @swati some articles i use to do that: https://medium.com/@lamvd0101/how-to-build-an-sdk-embed-react-native-ios-and-android-ab0e81b42333 

This was very useful: https://segmentfault.com/a/1190000041883802/en
also very important: https://appfiza.com/how-to-get-a-react-native-module-in-native-via-maven/

... maybe i should write my own article :D
btw good luck with that it is super interesting to do it this way but very very hard ....  we are in production right now ... so it is worth